# C# read and filter text

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to get my code to filter and start and end from specific word in a txt file.

Yeah, sorry. The question is, how to tell it to start from one line and stop at another?

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
  if (line.Contains("text"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

I will tr to specify what I'm planning to achieve.

it has to start from the line "Command              : Update" and stop on the end. The tricky part is, it has to start from the last "Command              : Update".

```
Command              : Update
Updating             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.doc
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.exe
External             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.fla
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.txt
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.doc
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile1.exe
Command              : Update
Updating             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.fla
External             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.txt
Updating             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.doc
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.exe
External             : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.fla
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.txt
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.doc
Completed            : C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.exe
```

The preferd output would be

```
C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.doc
C:\somepath\somepath\somefile222.doc
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do and what is not working in your code?

Comment: And the question is? Please clarify what you are trying to do, and what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Is the question that you need to print a file in reverse order, but only print out the lines containing specific text?

Comment: @itlsMeBen are you asking a question? where is your `Question Mark` ? I cannot find any question here.

Comment: btw: Isnt ReadLines() with .Reverse a kind of nonsense?

Comment: So you need to read through the file looking for something in particular, when you find that thing you want to start printing to the console and then when you find some other thing you want to stop printing to the console?

Comment: pstrjds. Yes. It has to have the whole line and even from that line i have to remove some parts of text.

Comment: No really I'm sure that this question request additional [tag:telepathy] skills...

Comment: Okay - based on your new update, what is it that defines the "preferred output". We now know that you want from the last command update to the end of the file, but do you only want it to print file names that end in .doc, do you only want if it says "Updating: " and the file is a .doc and then a matching "Completed:". Please explain what your requirement is. Also specify whether you know the rough size of the file that you are reading and if there is a known amount of lines to output, will it fit in memory? There is a reason this was tagged with the new tag "Telepathy".

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best code and could probably be cleaned up some, but this should get you started. This code will read lines looking for the text that indicates start writing. Then it will output lines until it finds the text that indicates done writing. At which point it won't read any more lines and will exit the loop.

```
bool output = false;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("C:\\test.txt"))
{
    if (!output && line.Contains("beginText"))
    {
        output = true;
    }
    else if (output && line.Contains("endText"))
    {
        break;
    }

    if (output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

**Edit** based on the question update:

I will leave the filtering out of the result lines to you since I am not sure what the rules are that define what should be output and what shouldn't, but here is a way to at least get the the results after the last update line:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Command\s+:\s+Update");
List<string> itemsToOutput = null;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("C:\\test.txt"))
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(line))
    {
        itemsToOutput = new List<string>();
        continue;
    }

    if (itemsToOutput != null)
    {
        itemsToOutput.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be what the op wants.. +1

Comment: @itIsMeBen - Feel free to upvote then :)  Once you have the list of lines to output, it should be trivial to filter out the lines and to split the text so that all you get is the file name.  If you had listed what defines your filtering of the output list I could have helped further. There are lots of rules one could apply to get your "preferred output".